# Upsampling in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to upsample in BigQuery? Let's say I have a table with `category` column with these counts

```
| category | count |
|    A     |  100  |
|    B     |  20   |
|    C     |  35   |
|    D     |  55   |
```

And I want to upsample the whole dataset based on the count of Category A, so the dataset would look like this when aggregated. Repeated rows are acceptable.

```
| category | count |
|    A     |  100  |
|    B     |  100  |
|    C     |  100  |
|    D     |  100  |
```

Comment: Would SELECT catagory, (select max(count) from some_table where category = 'A') from some_table work? Or select category, max(case when category = 'A' then count end) over ( partition by null)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, I don't think there's a simple way in BigQuery but I thought it can make a fun SQL challenge to solve.

I'll try to explain my solution to the best of my ability.

First I start by adding row numbers by categories to the initial table.
The idea is to create repeated random numbers for each category so that I can join them with the row numbers I added.

For example, for A I would have all the numbers from 1-100, but for B since there are only 20 samples, I would sample 100 times a random number from 1-20. And so forth for the other categories.

To do so, I would simply generate all numbers from 1-100 (or the maximum category), then apply modulo the number of samples in the category. For B, it would generate random numbers from 1-20.

My SQL is probably too verbose but it seems to be doing the job.
The column val is just a random column in the initial table.

```
with counts as (
  select category, 
  count(*) c 
  from example
  group by 1
),

max_c as (
  select max(c) as max_count 
  from counts
),

table_with_row_num as (
  select 
  category, 
  val, 
  row_number() over (partition by category) r 
  from example),

array_max_count as (
  select arr 
  from max_c, unnest(generate_array(1, max_c.max_count)) arr
),

template as (
  select category, 
   mod(arr, c) + 1 as m 
  from counts 
  full join
  array_max_count
  on 1=1
)

select t1.category, val
from template t1 
left join
table_with_row_num t2
on 
t1.category = t2.category and m = r
```